# How to add together the results of several subqueries?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am running a MySQL query to rank my site's users according to the number of book reviews and recipe reviews they have contributed. After initial issues with a multiple JOIN query, I've switched to a series of subqueries, which is much, much faster. However, although I can extract the numbers of reviews from each member, I can't figure out how to add them together so I can sort by the total number.

Here's the current query:

```
SELECT users.*,
   (SELECT count(*) FROM bookshelf WHERE bookshelf.user_id = users.ID) as titles,
   (SELECT count(*) FROM book_reviews WHERE book_reviews.user_id = users.ID) as bookreviews,
   (SELECT count(*) FROM recipe_reviews WHERE recipe_reviews.user_id = users.ID) as recipereviews
FROM users
```

I need to add together bookreviews and recipereviews to get 'reviewtotals'. MySQL won't allow you to use simple syntax to do calculations on aliases, but I presume there's another way to do this??

Comment: @mandel, I'm curious about your issues with `JOIN` typically, I solve this kind of problem with a `JOIN` - see my answer for reference. In my experience that is usually much faster for MySQL than multiple correlated subquerys like you have. I'd be interested to hear if in your case the subquery solution is faster than the JOIN. I'd appreciate it a lot if you could let me know.

Comment: My issues with JOIN came from inexperience rather than philosophy. My previous JOIN resulted in a terribly slow query - 9 seconds; turned out it was creating a Cartesian product. I asked about it on SO here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030032/is-performing-a-count-calculation-slowing-down-my-mysql-query. When I turned to doing subqueries, the speed improved dramatically, AND I could understand what I was doing!

Comment: See my answer to your post for a speed comparison - your JOIN query is a tiny bit faster, but only 4/100ths of a second at the current DB size.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wrap it into a subquery:

```
SELECT  *,
        bookreviews + recipereviews AS totalreviews
FROM    (
        SELECT  users.*,
                (SELECT count(*) FROM bookshelf WHERE bookshelf.user_id = users.ID) as titles,
                (SELECT count(*) FROM book_reviews WHERE book_reviews.user_id = users.ID) as bookreviews,
                (SELECT count(*) FROM recipe_reviews WHERE recipe_reviews.user_id = users.ID) as recipereviews
        FROM    users   
        ) q
```

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

Option 1:Ugly is hell, and probably slow (depends on the query cache):

```
SELECT users.*,
   (SELECT count(*) FROM bookshelf WHERE bookshelf.user_id = users.ID) as titles,
   (SELECT count(*) FROM book_reviews WHERE book_reviews.user_id = users.ID) as bookreviews,
   (SELECT count(*) FROM recipe_reviews WHERE recipe_reviews.user_id = users.ID) as recipereviews
   (SELECT count(*) FROM book_reviews WHERE book_reviews.user_id = users.ID) + (SELECT count(*) FROM recipe_reviews WHERE recipe_reviews.user_id = users.ID) as reviewtotals
FROM users
```

Option 2: Save the results to a temporary table and then query this table

Perhaps this will work (haven't tried it)

```
SELECT *, bookreviews+recipereviews as reviewtotals FROM
(SELECT users.*,
   (SELECT count(*) FROM bookshelf WHERE bookshelf.user_id = users.ID) as titles,
   (SELECT count(*) FROM book_reviews WHERE book_reviews.user_id = users.ID) as bookreviews,
   (SELECT count(*) FROM recipe_reviews WHERE recipe_reviews.user_id = users.ID) as recipereviews
FROM users) u
```

Comment: Number two almost works but you have to add an alias to the first subquery - then it's identical to @Quassnoi's solution, though, which was in a minute earlier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be safe and fast, do it like this:

```
SELECT users.*
,      titles.num                            titles
,      book_reviews.num                      book_reviews
,      recipe_reviews.num                    recipe_reviews
,      book_reviews.num + recipe_reviews.num total_reviews
FROM      users   
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT   user_ID, count(*) AS num
          FROM     bookshelf
          GROUP BY user_ID
          ) as titles
ON        users.ID = titles.user_ID
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT   user_ID, count(*) AS num
          FROM     book_reviews
          GROUP BY user_ID
          ) as book_reviews
ON        users.ID = reviews.user_ID
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT   user_ID, count(*) AS num
          FROM     recipe_reviews
          GROUP BY user_ID
          ) as recipe_reviews
ON        users.ID = recipes.user_ID
```

If you want to stick to the subqueries in the `SELECT` list, and want it to be safe, take a look at Quassnoi's solution.

If you like to live a bit dangersouly and still want a fast result, you can use user-defined variables. I predict it will be safe in this very particular case:

```
SELECT users.*,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM bookshelf WHERE bookshelf.user_id = users.ID) as titles,
       @bookreviews:=(
           SELECT count(*) 
           FROM book_reviews 
           WHERE book_reviews.user_id = users.ID
       ) as bookreviews,
       @recipereviews:=(
           SELECT count(*) 
           FROM recipe_reviews 
           WHERE recipe_reviews.user_id = users.ID
       ) as recipereviews,
       @bookreviews + @recipereviews as total_reviews
FROM users
```

Comment: Interesting: Option 1 is a tiny bit faster than Quassnoi's solution (0.02 sec vs 0.024 sec), while Option 2 is 0.88 sec, so comparatively quite a bit slower. I find Quassnoi's much simpler in terms of readability (and my understanding of what's going on). Are there advantages to using the JOIN method in your first example?

Comment: mandel: yes, the advantages become quickly apparent when the sets you are dealing with grow in size. the JOIN is much better scaleable. However, at these clock times, I don't think we can say anything conclusive. I would disregard such a small difference. But still you should see sizeable differences when you get more data to deal with. The subquery solution executes each subquery for each row of the outer query. A nested loop join is typically much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You tried the following?

```
SELECT users.*,
   (SELECT count(*) FROM bookshelf WHERE bookshelf.user_id = users.ID) as titles,
   ((SELECT count(*) FROM book_reviews WHERE book_reviews.user_id = users.ID) +
   (SELECT count(*) FROM recipe_reviews WHERE recipe_reviews.user_id = users.ID)) as reviewtotal
FROM users
```

Comment: Thanks - this is almost it, but I still need to generate totals from bookreviews and recipereviews as well as the calculated sum.